# CNContact contact framework ios 9.0

Tags: ios9, cncontact

Can I export custom contact label with following code

```
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let newContact = CNMutableContact()

    newContact.givenName = "Save"
    newContact.familyName = "Contact"
    newContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
               label:"Mobile1",
    value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"(498) 101-1123"))]
    do {
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.addContact(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
        try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
    }
    catch {
        NSLog("not saved")
    }
```

Until iOS 7.0/8.0 AddressBook:ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel was allowed custom label.
It seem it always saved with home or work label type. Any one tried this? 
Can app save custom label instead of below generic label??

```
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone                NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile                NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberMain                  NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberHomeFax               NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax               NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberOtherFax              NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelPhoneNumberPager                 NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelHome                             NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelWork                             NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
CONTACTS_EXTERN NSString * const CNLabelOther                            NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```